# How to install OS on WD My Book Live

Tags: linux, powerpc, nas

I'd like to create a custom NAS from a WD MY Book Live so I disassembled it, deleted everything from the HDD and successfully installed an Ubuntu server with another PC.
But it won't boot with it's own logicboard system because after some research I have to realize that it's a powerPC architecture stuff.

The logicboard only has an AC and a Ethernet port so there's no way to install Linux on place.

So, right now i'm stucked and I appreciate any help with it.

Comment: Search the Internet for a Linux distribution tailored to your specific NAS. An "off-the-shelf" Linux distro, even for PowerPC architectures, won't work, as the distro need specific details on how to boot, and discover, enumerate and configure built-in devices (you have most probably a SoC with a PowerPC CPU core)

Comment: What you're describing is an project requiring significant experience with embedded system design. Unfortunately, you don't appear to have that experience, and there's *much* more that you'd have to learn than we can feasibly impart in a single answer here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

*(I hit this qestion while searching for projects trying to do this. This is more a generic answer, not a specific one as I haven't actually done this and don't own a device.)*

In general, the best resources for NAS and other devices that might run Linux are the ports for the architecture (PowerPC in this case, often armel or armhf) or projects that are trying to make firmware for this type of devices.

A few useful sites:

- https://forum.doozan.com
- https://www.armbian.com/
- https://openwrt.org/
- https://www.debian.org/ports/powerpc/
- https://wiki.debian.org/DebianOnPowerPC

Here's some potentially specific links as well:

- https://aaronredding.com/mybooklive-fresh-install-debian-8/
- https://github.com/ewaldc/My-Book-Live/tree/master/debian/debian%208%20(Jessie)
- https://lwn.net/Articles/861235/